# Is it possible to create a link within a normal folder to the subversion repository on the server?

Tags: svn, webserver, repository, hyperlink

Suppose you have a server that manages an SVN repository. Now is it possible to create a link somewhere else on the server to the SVN repository directory (the most recent revision of the repository)? How are the files inside the repository actually stored on the server?

My intention is to have a symbolic link `/var/www/domain` to a folder `domain` in my repository to have a convienent way for synchronizing the files of a website that I design with the changes I do on my working machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to have a direct link to your repository that can be served as a website.

A lot of people use a post-commit hook to automatically deploy websites. You will find a ton of articles on how to do it, like [this one](http://brennydoogles.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/using-subversion-to-automatically-publish-your-website/) for example.

**But** it can indeed be a bad idea as you will have to wait for the deployment to complete on each commit (which can be long, unless your deployment process is very very quick). Your best bet would then be to use a [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) tool such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You synchronize files by checking out the repository to a local working copy and then use the SVN update command inside this working copy for pulling updates.  To send info into the repo you use commit from inside a working copy where you made the changes.  Do not directly mess with SVN repository files on your subversion server directly!!!